# "ReferenceError: ReactRedux is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am following the Redux tutorial and trying to include `Provider`. I am using JSbin

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.5/react-redux.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.js"></script>
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/expect@latest"></script>
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/deep-freeze@latest"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://fb/react-0.14.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://fb/react-dom-0.14.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id='root'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS File:

```
const { Provider } = ReactRedux;
```

However I am getting the error:

```
"ReferenceError: ReactRedux is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's just a typo (`scr` instead of `src`), voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet you posted, you have **scr** and not **src**.

```
<script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.5/react-redux.js"></script>
```

Should be

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.5/react-redux.js"></script>
```

Comment: Typo questions should get comments and (when you can) close-votes, not answers.